# How to typeset "$\rm kVp$" (kilovolt-peak) in CT physics?

Tags: voltage, conventions, notation, si-units, x-rays

I'm not a radiation physicist. Kilovolt-peak appears to be used as a unit, with descriptions such as "80 kVp". Should this be typeset as a single unit written "Vp", similar to e.g. "Gy" for Gray, or with the "p" as a subscript, or in some other way?

As someone not in the field, I'm not sure how to judge whether papers do this correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $p$ should not appear in the units at all, this is explicitly contrary to the SI. From the [NIST webpage](https://www.nist.gov/pml/special-publication-330) on the SI, section 5.4.2 it says

> Unit symbols must not be used to provide specific information about the quantity and should never be the sole source of information on the quantity. Units are never qualified by further information about the nature of the quantity; any extra information on the nature of the quantity should be attached to the quantity symbol and not to the unit symbol.

So an appropriate way to write this would be "the kilovolt peak is $U_{p} = 80\mathrm{\ kV}$". Per the SI instructions the designation "peak" or "p" must never be attached to the unit symbol.

Answer (score 1):

The volt peak unit is often typed as a single unit, Vp, in upright font (not italics), such that kilovolt peak becomes kVp. If you have kilovolt peak times meters (m) per second (s), the meters would be separate would : kVp m/s. This is the convention used for example in IEEE Editorial Style Manual for Authors.

Other authors prefer to write the p in peak in between parenthesis kV(p).